# how can i autoupdate a column in a table at a specified system time at 12:00 am

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

This is my table

```
demailid           no_of_pat      count
siri@gmail.com       20             3
lily@gmail.com       15             10
```

I want the column count to get updated to same as no_of_pat column at night  12:00 am.

How can i do this??Please suggest the solution.

Thank you..

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Answer (score 0):

It is generally poor design to update 'all' rows of a column repeatedly.  It is usually better to compute the value when `SELECTing` and/or have another table with very few rows that controls the 'adjustment' that is needed to that entire column.

It sounds like you want a daily count and a count that gets bumped as things happen.  Please describe your app further.  Probably you need a table with a counter and another table with daily sumtotals.  In this case the "update" happens the other direction -- At the end of the day, gather the daily counts and put them in the summary table.